# JNA - pass char* to function

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I'm writing a small program in Java JNA. I have some example of code in C++:

```
HMODULE m_hInstDLL = LoadLibrary("CommLib.DLL");
typedef bool (FAR WINAPI* FARPROC_ADVISE_UNADVISE)(long, char*,char*);
FARPROC_ADVISE_UNADVISE m_procSymbolX_Advise = (FARPROC_ADVISE_UNADVISE)GetProcAddress(m_hInstDLL, "SymbolX_Advise");
```

With help of this example I know that in Commlib.dll there is a function:

```
SymbolX_Advise(long, char*, char*)
```

Where long it's handler for my window(HWND), and pointers to char array.
How to pass in JNA pointer to char array?
I wrote something like this in Java with help of JNA:

```
boolean SymbolX_Advise(int handle, Pointer plc, Pointer tagName);
instance = (CommLib) Native.loadLibrary("CommLib", CommLib.class);
Pointer ptr1 = new Memory(plc.length()+1);
ptr1.setString(0, plc);
Pointer ptr2 = new Memory(tagName.length()+1);
ptr2.setString(0, tagName);
instance.SymbolX_Advise(windowHandler, ptr1, ptr2);
```

Is the right way to pass this pointers? Because now it isn't working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JNA: char array as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742387/jna-char-array-as-function-parameter)

Comment: Also, I am not familiar with *Java* integer types, but *HANDLE* is 8 bytes long on *Win* 64bit.

Comment: You added the +1 for the null terminator but did you ensure that the `Memory` was cleared when you set the string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I ran into a very similar situation months ago. I had C++ function with JNA that took in a string. It didn't take the string as an argument because of the difference between the encodings in C++ and Java, well I am assuming that anyway. I passed it as a pointer to a character array in C++. I don't have my code with me, but I think if you define it as a string in Java and then pass it will work. I know I didn't use that syntax and I didn't use a pointer to pass it.